# Django 1.6.5 STATIC_URL in templates

Tags: django, django-static

I really need your help. I know that this question has been asked many times, but now I'm faced with strange behavior of django 1.6.5. The problem is that in my project stopped working STATIC_URL's in templates. My settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

- BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**))

Other settings are set to default.

{{ STATIC_URL }} in template returns empty sting.

I try to use STATICFILES_FINDERS, TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings - nothing has changed.

Attempts to changes in views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))



@render_to('index.html')
def home(request):
    return {}
```

Comment: In your `settings.py` what's your `DEBUG` value?

Comment: DEBUG = True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

Comment: Also I use python 3.4.1

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference. Before it happened, I've found in the external-libraries "sass-stdlib" and removed it. Maybe my pyCharm did something without my will?

Comment: I'm currently using python 2.7.1. I'm not familiar with python 3